# Hide primary keys or ids from being exposed

Tags: django, primary-key, django-urls, identifier

Currently while adding, editing or deleting a object i am using the id (pk) of the object in the urls which of course exposes the global primary key id of that particular object to the users. I somehow want to hide those global id's from the urls and/or from the hidden fields within a form while using POST.

Just to make it a little more clear let me explain this with an example. So say i have the following models.

## Models.py

```
class Profile(User)
    # Some fields here


class Student(Profile)
    # some fields here


class Teacher(Profile)
    # Some fields here


class Project(models.Model)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    # some more fields here.
```

according to the above models, say i want to either edit or delete an existing `Project` instance. what I currently do is use the `id(pk)` as an argument in the urls as follows:

## Urls.py

```
url(r'^project/(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', 'app.views.edit_project'),
url(r'^project/(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', 'app.views.delete_project'),
```

what would be the best approach to either completely hide these id's from the url?

is there a way we could have Project Id's per student ? something like adding another `auto_increment` column to the Project table ?

Comment: Why do you feel that this would be useful?

Comment: to be safe from attackers i guess? , i personally don't think it's a good idea to publicly expose the primary key of any entity.

Comment: If your project performs proper authorization then whoever gets a look at the primary keys won't be able to discern very much.

Comment: i do agree with that, but my project has multiple model objects that are owned by other model object so for example say a Student is owner of a project. Currently we do check for ownership in the views. but say, 6 months down the line, a developer forgets to check for ownership while writing code for the view for a similar object, that object might be available to say a Teacher object who in this case is not the owner but is authenticated. How would i go about this ? My only concern is to be on the safer side.

Comment: You could add a slug (SlugField) and use it in your urls.py

Comment: If you can't trust a developer to handle security as it is written in the coding guidelines then they shouldn't be developing in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SlugField()` option proposed by Antony is a great idea. Put a unique constraint on the field (`unique=True` in your model definition). Then write your `urls.py` rules like this:

```
url(r'^project/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/edit/$', 'app.views.edit_project'),
url(r'^project/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/delete/$', 'app.views.delete_project'),
```

Comment: Thanks, as Antony suggested i have managed to change the code to use `SlugField()` instead of `pk`'s and it's working as expected. Also, i did find this snippet pretty useful for auto populating the slugs on `save()`

Comment: For slugifying a field yourself, use Django's built-in slugify function.  Run `from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify` and then `slugify(myString)`. You can put this in your `save()` override.